# Not getting the correct response for an automorphic number

Tags: java

I was writing a program to check if a number is automorphic or not. I decided to test the program. But somehow, when I entered a number greater than 9376, it said that it was not an automorphic number.

Link for automorphic number: [Automorphic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphic_number)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int copy=n,ex=0;
        while(n!=0){
            n/=10;
            ex++;
        }
        if((copy*copy)%(Math.pow(10,ex))==copy){
            System.out.println(copy+" is an automorphic number.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(copy+" is not an automorphic number.");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried it with 5, 25, 76, 376 and it gave me the correct response. But when I entered 90625 or other numbers, it replied in negative.

Output for reference:

```
90625
90625 is not an automorphic number.
9376
9376 is an automorphic number.
```

Comment: I do not trust `pow()` with integers, but that might just be because I am more at home in a different language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large integers (like 90625), squaring it (`copy * copy`) will result in an integer overflow.

If you print the value of `copy * copy` for 90625, you'll get -377043967.

To fix this, you can make the variable `copy` of type `long`.

However, you have to decide what is the maximum or largest number you'll ever want this to work for. If the square of that number won't fit within the bounds of a `long`, then you'd have to use a BigInteger. Since you had the input as an `int`, using a `long` should be good enough for you (A `long` can hold the result of `Integer.MAX_VALUE * Integer.MAX_VALUE`).